# GLScene Поворот вокруг грани

Tags: delphi, opengl, 3d

Разбираюсь с 3D графикой Delphi GLScene. Пытаюсь повернуть куб вокруг своей грани.

Поворот вокруг своей оси реализуется просто

```
GlCube1.Pitch(deltatime*10);
GlCube1.Turn(deltatime*10);
GlCube1.Roll(deltatime*10);
```

Покопался в функциях: предположительно это можно сделать с помощью

```
procedure TGLBaseSceneObject.RotateAbsolute(const axis: TAffineVector; angle: Single);
```

Разобраться не смог. На правильном ли я пути? Или есть другие способы?

Comment: кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, что значит "поворот вокруг грани"?

Comment: @Igor Я это понял как "ось вращения принадлежит грани куба".

Comment: @ViktorTomilov так, хорошо. Чем тогда это отличается от поворота вокруг любой другой произвольной оси?

Comment: @Igor Для поворота вокруг любой произвольной оси мы не можем пользоваться этими тремя простыми методами, на которые сослался автор. Фактически, нам придется делать сдвиг системы координат. Чтобы не мучаться с перерасчётами (а в функциях вращения используются цилиндрические и сферические модели, а не декартовы), проще применить DummyCube, который и сдвинет систему координат на нужное нам значение, а затем просто применить Pitch, Turn или Roll, но уже к нему, а не к нашему GlCube1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, на моих машинах сейчас установить GLScene нельзя. Пишу по памяти.
В этом случае используется объявление объекта `DummyCube` в нужную вам позицию - например, в координаты (0,0,0). `DummyCube` прозрачен, но с ним можно проводить те же операции вращения. В него вы помещаете уже свой непрозрачный куб `GlCube1` так, чтобы грань, вокруг которой вы собрались его вращать, лежала на одной из стандартных осей вращения `DummyCube`. Всё, теперь, вращая `DummyCube`, вы вращаете и свой кубик так, как вам нужно.

Объекты `DummyCube` как раз и используются для группировки, для упрощения вращения.

Comment: Спасибо, классное решение